# too much space between two environment create with tcolorbox

Tags: fancyvrb, tcolorbox

i want write a maple book, see this example code in that book:

```
‎\documentclass{article}‎
‎\usepackage{tcolorbox,fancyvrb}‎
‎\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}‎‎
‎‎
‎‎‎‎‎‎%-------------------------------------------------- ‎Code ‎Environment‎
‎\newenvironment{‎code‎}‎
 ‎{\VerbatimEnvironment‎
  ‎\begin{tcolorbox}[‎
    ‎breakable‎,
    ‎colback=red!5!white,‎‎
    ‎colframe=red!75!‎black‎,
  ]%
  ‎\begin{Verbatim}}‎
 ‎{\end{Verbatim}\end{tcolorbox}}‎
‎
‎\newenvironment{‎outc‎‎‎}‎
 ‎{‎‎\begin{tcolorbox}[‎
    ‎breakable‎,‎
    left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0‎mm,‎
%    ‎boxsep=0mm,
    ‎colback=‎white,‎‎
    coltext=‎blue‎,‎
    ‎‎colframe=‎gray!50‎‎,
  ]‎‎‎}‎%‎
 ‎{‎\end{tcolorbox}}‎
‎
%‎\newenvironment{‎outcode‎‎}‎
% ‎{‎‎\begin{‎outc‎}‎\begin{equation}} 
% {\end{‎equation‎}‎‎‎\end{‎outc‎‎}}‎
‎\newenvironment{‎outcode‎‎}‎
 ‎{‎‎\begin{‎outc‎}‎\[‎} 
 {‎\]‎\end{‎outc‎‎}}‎
‎%-------------------------------------------------- ‎Code ‎Environment‎

‎\begin{document}‎‎
‎‎
‎In this example, we see too much space between this two environment ‎\textbf{code} and ‎\textbf{outcode}‎:‎
‎
‎‎‎‎‎\begin{‎code}‎
> ‎‎‎2+3;‎ 
‎\end{‎code‎}‎‎
‎\begin{‎‎‎outcode‎}‎
‎5‎
‎\end{‎outcode‎}‎
‎
‎\end{document}‎‎‎
```

output is:

[image]

question is:
How can i write output below the maple code with two different color for background and text,and separate those with, for example \tcblower command in tcolorbox?

In tcolorbox-example.tex file in **c:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\doc\latex\tcolorbox** folder,
use environment **tcblisting** for the setting the box
displays the source code and shows the output in other part below like this:

```
‎\begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}‎
‎This is a \LaTeX\ example‎:
‎\begin{equation}‎
‎\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}‎.
‎\end{equation}‎
‎\end{tcblisting}‎
```

output is:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of two separate `tcolorboxe`s, use just one with the `listing and comment` option; in this way, the upper part of the box will be used for the listing and the lower part, for the “comment”, which can be almost anything, in particular, the output of the code; the `bicolor` skin allows you to control the color for both parts (upper and lower) independently:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\newtcblisting{codeoutput}[1]{
breakable,
listing and comment,
bicolor,
lower separated=true,
colback=red!5,
colframe=red!75!black,
colbacklower=white,
collower=blue,
comment=#1,
overlay={
  \draw[dashed,red!80!black] (segmentation.west)--(segmentation.east);
  },
listing options={
  language={Matlab},
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeoutput}{5}
> 2+3; nnnnn
\end{codeoutput}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\newtcblisting{codeoutput}[1]{
breakable,
listing and comment,
bicolor,
frame style={
  draw=black,
  color=Maroon
  },
colback=black,
colbacklower=Dandelion!15,
colupper=white,
collower=Maroon,
comment=#1,
listing options={
  language={Matlab},
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeoutput}{5}
> 2+3; nnnnn
\end{codeoutput}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Nice and helpful answer (as always ;-). I only removed the needless and potentially dangerous `\tcblower` command inside the `codeoutput` examples. A *comment* inside a `tcblisting` is automatically placed in the lower part when `listing and comment` is used.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thanks for the edit. I must have left the `\tcblower` there from test codes I used when building the answer.