# It is possible to define "styles" in tcolorbox listings?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I am writing a document where I use `tcolorbox` to list code. I would like to have a couple of commands to list code from an external file, and one (or two) environment for inline snippets. What I have (and it's nicely working) is something along the way of this MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    return 0;
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[listings, breakable, skins, fitting]{tcolorbox}

% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163617/38080
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter]{\putcodecomment}[2]{
    listing file={#1},
    title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #1}, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    listing and comment,
    comment={#2},
    %%% start of common things here 
    breakable,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    bicolor,
    lower separated=true,
    colback=red!5,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    listing options={
      language          = {[Visual]C++},           % Language
      basicstyle        = \ttfamily,             % Default format          
      keywordstyle      = \color{blue},          % Keywordformat                               
      breaklines        = true,                  % Automatic line breaks
      breakatwhitespace = true,                  % Line breaks only at white spaces
      tabsize           = 4,                     % Number of spaces equal to a tab
      showspaces        = false,                 % Show spaces in the code
      showtabs          = false,                 % Show tabs in the code
      showstringspaces  = false,                 % Show spaces among strings
  },
}

\newtcblisting{justcode}[0]{
    listing only,
    breakable,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    %%% start of common things here 
    breakable,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    bicolor,
    lower separated=true,
    colback=red!5,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    listing options={
      language          = {[Visual]C++},           % Language
      basicstyle        = \ttfamily,       % Default format          
      keywordstyle      = \color{blue},          % Keywordformat                               
      breaklines        = true,                  % Automatic line breaks
      breakatwhitespace = true,                  % Line breaks only at white spaces
      tabsize           = 4,                     % Number of spaces equal to a tab
      showspaces        = false,                 % Show spaces in the code
      showtabs          = false,                 % Show tabs in the code
      showstringspaces  = false,                 % Show spaces among strings
  },
}

\begin{document}

\putcodecomment{test.c}{%
    No comment here 
}

\begin{justcode}
    a = a + 1; 
\end{justcode}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

... which works, but as you can see, I had to use copy and paste to "repeat" the common part of the options of the boxes. Now, if I want to change the color of the background, I need to change it in two (really they are four) different place.

I tried to put all the common option in a `\def\commonoptions{...}` but it choked...

Is there a way to put the common part in common "style" so that I can organize it better? Something on the line of the `tikz` styles?

Comment: Do you mean a listing style or a `tcolorbox` style?

Comment: ...really the two of them.

Comment: Then try the second version of my answer, at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\lstdefinestyle{foo}{ your options}` and say `listing options={style=foo}`, this will save a lot of typing (or work).

You can change the listing options after setting the style:

`listing options={style=foo,numbers=right}`, for example.

Here's a modified version of the O.P. code

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    return 0;
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[listings, breakable, skins, fitting]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{rmano}{      language          = {[Visual]C++},           % Language
      basicstyle        = \ttfamily,             % Default format          
      keywordstyle      = \color{blue},          % Keywordformat                               
      breaklines        = true,                  % Automatic line breaks
      breakatwhitespace = true,                  % Line breaks only at white spaces
      tabsize           = 4,                     % Number of spaces equal to a tab
      showspaces        = false,                 % Show spaces in the code
      showtabs          = false,                 % Show tabs in the code
      showstringspaces  = false,                 % Show spaces among strings
}

% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163617/38080
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter]{\putcodecomment}[2]{
    listing file={#1},
    title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #1}, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    listing and comment,
    comment={#2},
    %%% start of common things here 
    breakable,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    bicolor,
    lower separated=true,
    colback=red!5,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    listing options={style=rmano}
  }

\newtcblisting{justcode}[0]{
    listing only,
    breakable,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    %%% start of common things here 
    breakable,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    bicolor,
    lower separated=true,
    colback=red!5,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    listing options={style={rmano},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\putcodecomment{test.c}{%
    No comment here 
}

\begin{justcode}
    a = a + 1; 
\end{justcode}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Here's a version that has common options for `tcolorbox` as well:

Use

```
\def\commonboxoptions{    breakable,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    bicolor,
    lower separated=true,
    colback=red!5!,
    colframe=red!75!black,
}
```

and say `code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\commonboxoptions}}` in the `tcolorbox` options (the `listing boxes` here!)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    return 0;
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[listings, breakable, skins, fitting]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{rmano}{      language          = {[Visual]C++},           % Language
      basicstyle        = \ttfamily,             % Default format          
      keywordstyle      = \color{blue},          % Keywordformat                               
      breaklines        = true,                  % Automatic line breaks
      breakatwhitespace = true,                  % Line breaks only at white spaces
      tabsize           = 4,                     % Number of spaces equal to a tab
      showspaces        = false,                 % Show spaces in the code
      showtabs          = false,                 % Show tabs in the code
      showstringspaces  = false,                 % Show spaces among strings
}

\def\commonboxoptions{    breakable,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    bicolor,
    lower separated=true,
    colback=red!5!,
    colframe=red!75!black,
}

% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163617/38080
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter]{\putcodecomment}[2]{
    listing file={#1},
    title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #1}, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    listing and comment,
    comment={#2},
    %%% start of common things here 
    code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\commonboxoptions}},
    listing options={style=rmano}
  }

\newtcblisting{justcode}[0]{
    listing only,
    breakable,
    width=0.9\linewidth,
    %%% start of common things here 
    code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\commonboxoptions}},
    listing options={style={rmano},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\putcodecomment{test.c}{%
    No comment here 
}

\begin{justcode}
    a = a + 1; 
\end{justcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I can also put the `listing options={style=rmano}` into the macro `\commonboxoptions` and it works!

Comment: @Rmano: Yes, I considered that too, but I thought you would specifiy slightly different options to the different boxes, that's why I kept it outside!