# How to display code listing as in StackOverflow or Github?

Tags: listings

There is no day in which I do not look at StackOverflow code or at Github readmes, and I really like the way the code is displayed.

I would like to achieve a similar result in latex, i.e. a monospaced text inside a light grey box which can span multiple lines.

*How can I achieve this?*

So far: [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357227/adding-background-color-to-verb-or-lstinline-command-without-colorbox) is great for displaying inline text with a sugar syntax, but I have not been able to extend it to multiple lines without getting an ugly result, display in the Minimal Working Example here below.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings,realboxes,fancyvrb} % fancyvrb for '\Verb' macro
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, breaklines = true, backgroundcolor=\color{mygray}}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} % just for this example

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
-- the following code employs Lua's powerful "string.gsub" function
function color_lstinline ( s )
   s = string.gsub ( s , "\\lstinline%b||", "\\Colorbox{mygray}{%0}" ) 
   s = string.gsub ( s , "\\[vV]erb%b||", "\\Colorbox{mygray}{%0}" ) 
   return s
end
\end{luacode}
%% Define 2 LaTeX macros to switch operation of Lua function on and off
\newcommand{\ColorLstinlineOn}{\directlua{
   luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , 
   color_lstinline, "color_lstinline" )}}
\newcommand{\ColorLstinlineOff}{\directlua{
   luatexbase.remove_from_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , 
   "color_lstinline" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\ColorLstinlineOn} % Default: activate the Lua function 

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
This is my \lstinline|amazing| code.
This is my \verb|@#$%^&*()\%| code.
This is my \Verb!amazing! code. 
This is my \Colorbox{mygray}{\lstinline!amazing!} code.

This is part of the code I used for displaying this document:
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{luacode}
-- the following code employs Lua's powerful "string.gsub" function
function color_lstinline ( s )
   s = string.gsub ( s , "\\lstinline%b||", "\\Colorbox{mygray}{%0}" ) 
   s = string.gsub ( s , "\\[vV]erb%b||", "\\Colorbox{mygray}{%0}" ) 
   return s
end
\end{luacode}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Use a `lstlisting` **environment** istead of `\lstinline` command as proposed in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357339/141947) from the question you mentioned

Comment: I tried to do it but the result is ugly: the distance between lines is too big and each line is contained in a grey rectangle, this means that there is not an uniform grey background but multiple grey rectangles separated by a thin white line

Comment: I see what you mean, but this could be related to your pdf viewer. In any case, could you please update you question with some image showing the output as well as a MWE of you document ?

Comment: The defaults are ugly indeed. So you need to adjust the fonts, spacing etc. to your liking. It takes time but it is worth the effort. Search for listing questions on this site. Start making the font Consolas.

Comment: @percusse ok, what about the lines between the grey rectangles?

Comment: That's just your PDF viewer. Zoom in or out and they (re)appear.

Comment: Following what @percusse said, I have the same kind of result, but it'really a matter of the PDF viewer you use. Another solution could be to use the `tcblisting` of `tcolorbox` as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280341/it-is-possible-to-define-styles-in-tcolorbox-listings?rq=1)